# How exp(-z) is working in a sigmoid function in neural networks while z is a matrix?

Tags: neural-network, logistic-regression, octave, matrix

```
function g = sigmoid(z)

%SIGMOID Compute sigmoid function
%J = SIGMOID(z) computes the sigmoid of z.

g = 1.0 ./ (1.0 + exp(-z));

end
```

I'm going through the Andrew Ng Coursera course. I doubt that how `exp(-z)` is computed directly while `z` is a matrix?

Comment: Word of advice: You are really have to think in terms of vectors and matrices instead of scalars (ok, an scalar is just a funny word to say "single number"). This will be particularly important when calculating the loss too!

Answer (score 2):

In many languages and libraries, operations that apply to a scalar can be applied to vectors, matrices and tensors. They're just applied element-wise, and the result is another vector, matrix, etc with each value transformed by that function.